# rotation doesn't work in my code as3

Tags: actionscript-3

this is my code:

```
var grav:Number = 10;
var jumping:Boolean = false;
var jumpPow:Number = 0;

man.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, spring); // Add the button click

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);

function spring(e:MouseEvent):void {

        if(jumping != true)
        {   
            man.rotation = 360;
            jumpPow = -50;
            jumping = true;
        }
    }   



function update(evt:Event):void
{
    if(jumping)
    {
        man.y += jumpPow;
        jumpPow += grav;

        if(man.y >= 375)
        {
            jumping = false;
            man.y = 375;
        }
    }
}
```

I want man to rotate 360 degrees when it jumps.
I think that I have to use variables or the rotation code isn't right, but I'm a verry noob in coding so please help meeee/??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just setting the rotation to 360, in order to see it move gradually, you need to increment the rotation over time.

You can either use Flash's default tweening or get TweenLite or TweenMax to do it rather simply like this :

```
TweeenLite.to(man, 1, {rotation:360});
```

That would rotate your man 360 degrees over 1 second.

You could handle the rotation in other ways, but given you are starting out, this will get you there quickest.

You can google TweenLite if you want to go that route.

If you go with Flash's tweening, you can just google "AS3 Tween"